# Few Black lines on laptop display

Tags: laptop, display

I really need your help with black lines on my laptop Asus UX330 display.

https://i.ibb.co/cDkJN8w/669246.jpg

As you can see from the picture above, there are few black lines.

Strange thing is,the black lines can sometimes turn into "thick lines", sometimes it go back to thin lines. ( This is why I dont think this is due to dead pixels as the line can disappear and reappear randomly. This happens very rarely though). I also dont think this happen because of "cable connection". I meant, closing and opening the lid didnt do anything. I also tried pressing the edge of the screen without any result.

I dont think this is due to driver, as the black lines still appear when the laptop is in BIOS.

But the sure thing is, the number of lines keep increasing and in general it's getting thicker and thicker.

My question is, are these black lines caused by display or chipset problem?

I will buy a new display and change it myself, but I am afraid the problem lies not with the display but with the chipset.

Is there a possible way to know whether the chipset is the one who causes this problem or not without having an external monitor? I cant get either an external monitor/ HDMI cable..

I only have phone (obviously) and a 2nd laptop. Is it possible to check whether the chipset i faulty with a phone or a 2nd laptop? (I watched a youtube video where you can use laptop as a 2nd monitor with windows 10 feature)

Thankyou very much for your help :)

Comment: Can you not test with a TV with HDMI? In my experience, this is probably a graphics chip issue if it's not a physical issue (connection or bad panel). It's hard to say for sure without more information.

Answer (score 2):

Since the display issue happens in BIOS, it is not a Driver issue and most likely not Chipset either. Try hooking up an external monitor to verify this, but it seems to me that the laptop display needs to be replaced.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply John! Is there a possible way to know whether the chipset is the one who causes this problem or not without having an external monitor? Can I use my 2nd laptop as a 2nd monitor with the windows10 feature to test this? (no HDMI cable necessary)

Comment: Agreed, it appears to be hardware damage to the monitor itself, which can be verified by plugging in an external monitor.

Comment: Unfortunately, most laptops cannot receive video without extra hardware.  An actual monitor is probably needed to test the output.

Comment: Chipset interacts with the display workings in Windows but does not play a part in BIOS (so far as I know)